# QT 5.14, qml; Браузер при открытии любого сайта завершается

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator, qml

Проблема в браузере на qml.

**untiled6.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += webengine

SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <qtwebengineglobal.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("QtExamples");
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QtWebEngine::initialize();

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtWebEngine 1.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 1600
    height: 1200
    title: qsTr("WebEngineAction Example")
    minimumWidth: 500

    header: ToolBar {
        RowLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent

            ToolButton {
                property int itemAction: WebEngineView.Back
                text: webEngineView.action(itemAction).text
                enabled: webEngineView.action(itemAction).enabled
                onClicked: webEngineView.action(itemAction).trigger()
                icon.name: webEngineView.action(itemAction).iconName
                display: AbstractButton.TextUnderIcon
            }

            ToolButton {
                property int itemAction: WebEngineView.Forward
                text: webEngineView.action(itemAction).text
                enabled: webEngineView.action(itemAction).enabled
                onClicked: webEngineView.action(itemAction).trigger()
                icon.name: webEngineView.action(itemAction).iconName
                display: AbstractButton.TextUnderIcon
            }

            ToolButton {
                property int itemAction: webEngineView.loading ? WebEngineView.Stop : WebEngineView.Reload
                text: webEngineView.action(itemAction).text
                enabled: webEngineView.action(itemAction).enabled
                onClicked: webEngineView.action(itemAction).trigger()
                icon.name: webEngineView.action(itemAction).iconName
                display: AbstractButton.TextUnderIcon
            }

            TextField {
                Layout.fillWidth: true

                text: webEngineView.url
                selectByMouse: true
                onEditingFinished: webEngineView.url = text

            }

        }
    }

    WebEngineView {
        id: webEngineView
        url: "http://google.com"
        anchors.fill: parent

        Component.onCompleted: {
            profile.downloadRequested.connect(function(download){
                download.accept();
            })
        }

        property Menu contextMenu: Menu {
            Repeater {
                model: [
                    WebEngineView.Back,
                    WebEngineView.Forward,
                    WebEngineView.Reload,
                    WebEngineView.SavePage,
                    WebEngineView.Copy,
                    WebEngineView.Paste,
                    WebEngineView.Cut
                ]
                MenuItem {
                    text: webEngineView.action(modelData).text
                    enabled: webEngineView.action(modelData).enabled
                    onClicked: webEngineView.action(modelData).trigger()
                    icon.name: webEngineView.action(modelData).iconName
                    display: MenuItem.TextBesideIcon
                }
            }
        }

        onContextMenuRequested: function(request) {
            if (customContextMenuOption.checked) {
                request.accepted = true;
                contextMenu.popup();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**КОД ОШИБКИ**

```
23:25:22: Запускается /home/mylove/build-untitled6-Desktop_Qt_5_14_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/untitled6 ...
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
23:27:27: Программа неожиданно завершилась.
23:27:27: Процесс был завершён принудительно.
23:27:27: /home/mylove/build-untitled6-Desktop_Qt_5_14_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/untitled6 аварийно завершился.
```

**БУДУ КРАЙНЕ БЛАГОДАРЕН ЗА ЛЮБУЮ ПОМОЩЬ:)**

Comment: А браузер где????

В отладчике запускали?

Comment: отладчик сказал:

Приложение остановлено, так как оно получило сигнал от операционной системы.

Сигнал: 
SIGSEGV
Назначение: 
Segmentation fault

Comment: И все,? Стэка вызовов нет?

Comment: Если стека вызовов нету, значит внутри QT-шных либ что-то упало. Насколько я помню, есть возможность включить все их логи, по ним может понятнее станет почему падает

Comment: Благодарю, попробую

Comment: Вероятно, если падает не в Вашем коде, а в Qt-шном, то Вы как-то неправильно используете qml. `import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11` там разве не 2.* версия должна быть ?